# Unable to retrive information using where clause rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

So I have three Tables:

1. User
2. Customer
3. Appointment

`Customer` has_many `Appointments`, `Customer`  belongs_to  `User`

I have a required where I have to retrieve `Appointments` based on the `email` of the `customer`. I have the `email` field in the `User` table.

I tried the following query:

```
Appointment.joins(:customer).where("customers.users.email ILIKE test")
```

gave me this error:

```
 Appointment Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "appointments".* FROM "appointments" INNER JOIN "customers" ON "customers"."id" = "appointments"."customer_id" WHERE (customers.users.email ILIKE test)
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "users"
LINE 1: ...omers"."id" = "appointments"."customer_id" WHERE (customers....
                                                             ^
: SELECT "appointments".* FROM "appointments" INNER JOIN "customers" ON "customers"."id" = "appointments"."customer_id" WHERE (customers.users.email ILIKE test)
```

I tried adding this:

```
 belongs_to :customer, inverse_of: :appointments
 belongs_to :user, through: :customer
```

and also

```
has_one :customer_user, through: :customer
```

Obviously none of those things worked. I also tried this in customer model:

```
delegate :email, to: :user, prefix: true
```

and query:

```
User.joins(:customer).where("customers.user_email ILIKE test")
```

Throws the following error:

```
User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "customers" ON "customers"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."active" = 't' AND (customers.user_email ILIKE test)
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column customers.user_email does not exist
LINE 1: ...leted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."active" = 't' AND (customers....
                                                             ^
: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "customers" ON "customers"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."active" = 't' AND (customers.user_email ILIKE test)
```

How do I fetch Appointments with a customer having a particular email id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to filter on `users` table, you need to include it in the `join`.  Try:

```
Appointment.joins([customer: :user]).where("users.email ILIKE test")
```

This will create a join between `appointments` and `customers` and `customers` and `users` allowing you to filter on `users` table columns.

Comment: `Appointment.joins([customer: :user]).where("users.email ILIKE ?","test")` only work. Thanks! Will accept this when I am allowed to SO. Cheerio!

Comment: @Arvind, yes that's perfect.  Glad to be of help.